# error: invalid operands to binary + (have 'float**' and 'float**')

Tags: функции, структуры, типы

Пытаюсь скомпилировать следующий код:

```
typedef struct m {
    float** array[3][3];
} Matrix;

Matrix sum(Matrix A, Matrix B) {
    int i, j;
        Matrix C;
        for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            for (j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                C.array[i][j] = A.array[i][j] + B.array[i][j];
        return C;
```

Появляется следующая ошибка:

> error:  invalid operands to binary + (have 'float**' and 'float**')

Типы, вроде, одинаковые, но почему она появляется, не понимаю.

Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: У вас двумерный массив двойных указателей. Операция сложения для указателей не определена. Объявите массив как `float array[3][3];`